# Set up a trigger in google app script to send email automatically when user information is inserted into a new row using dopost()

Tags: android, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have made a qr scanner in android that sends the value to google sheets using `dopost()` now i want to setup a trigger to automatically send mail to the user whenever a new row is inserted into the google sheets.

I have tried `onEdit()` and `onChange()` but it's not working

Comment: I don’t think you need a trigger. Just  do it in the doPost()

Comment: Did you create the onEdit() and onChange() functions in "Edit -> Current Project's triggers"?

Comment: yes i have but the problem seems that since i have updated the data through script onEdit() is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Did you create a web app to insert data into a Spreadsheet?  Your question suggests that because you say `when user information is inserted into a new row using doPost()`.   So to be clear doPost() and doGet() are used to support get requests and posts from a webapp.  If that is what you are doing then please make it more clear.

But it sounds to me that your expecting the onEdit() to trigger a change when the webapp changes the data in the spreadsheet.  Unfortunately, that's not going to happen. The documentation from Simple Triggers states `onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet.`  not when your script changes a value.

But really why don't you just send the email when you update the spreadsheet information with another Google Apps Script.

**Question  Response**

Since your using doPost() why don't you just use a form and then you don't have pass everything in the query string.

```
function addItem(e){ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
  var date = new Date(); 
  var Roomnumber = e.parameter.Roomnumber; 
  var email = e.parameter.email; 
  sheet.appendRow([date,Roomnumber,email]); 
} 


function sendEmails() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(),1,1,3);
  var values = range.getValues;
  var date=values[0][0];
  var roomnumbeer=values[0][1];
  var email=values[0][2];
  //code to send mail 
}
```

Comment: yes i have made a web app that inserts data into the spreadsheet. Okay so how do i add another app script to that data? do i transfer the data to another sheet and write a script on that sheet?

Comment: I’m just suggesting that you send the email when you change the data with the same script

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("url");
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
function doPost(e){
var action = e.parameter.action;

if(action == 'addItem'){
  
 return addItem(e);
     
}
}
  
function addItem(e){
var date =  new Date();
 var Roomnumber = e.parameter.Roomnumber;
 var email = e.parameter.email;
  sheet.appendRow([date,Roomnumber,email]);
}  
 function sendEmails() {     
  //code to send mail 
         }  - This is my code can you please tell me how do i  send the email when i change the data with the same script

Comment: Answer to above question in my answer.

Comment: Can you check if your triggers are getting any error when they execute? I had some issues with the openByUrl sheet. Try calling it this way:
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = sheet.getActiveSheet();
Also, call your sendEmails() from an onEdit()

Comment: @cooper I don't want to use a form because i don't want users to enter details every time they scan a Qr code. Also there is some errors cause i guess the script is running but the email is not being sent. Also i change [0],[1] to [i],[1] . because that is cell number right?

Comment: @Jescanellas. That is because getActiveSheet(); works for an untitled googlen sheet and if you have named the google sheet . we use openByUrl.

Comment: If you not using a form then why not use doGet();

Comment: @cooper See both my dopost() and sendmail() are working fine . its just that trigger is not working. Like if i choose onOpen then i have to refresh the sheet evertime a data is inserted .The  problem is even if i write doget() still the script would add the data onto the sheet so Onchange() and onEdit() wont work.

Comment: Can you check if your executions are getting a Completed or Failed status? If so, what error does it say?